# Get rid of warning on Outlook addin Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

I'm writing an outlook Addin in C#/VS 2010, and eventhouh my application works fine, I would like to get rid fo this warning:

'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlInspectorClose)' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event.Close'. Using method group.

But I don't understand why it is being caused.

Comment: Please provide some related source and complete error message.

Answer (score 7):

If the full error looks like

> Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlInspectorClose)' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event.Close'. Using method group.

then most likely you are encountering a casting issue similar to what is described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/c998e245-80db-4ef4-9225-cc85d1cd64d8).

Comment: Yes, it was that, I just added the proper cast.

Answer (score 0):

Try call this way:

(oMsg as _MailItem).Close();